# Spring MongoDB MongoTemplate Aggregate query, how to return a List<List<Object>>

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I searched in vain and now pose my question to the masses.

- I have a Collection of `GpsRecord`, and each `GpsRecord` belongs to a `TrackRecord`
- Each `GpsRecord` holds an `ObjectId` referring to its parent `TrackRecord`
- I want to query the `GpsRecord` collection based on a list of `TrackRecord.ids`

From this query I would like to return a `List<List<GpsRecord>>` from an aggregate query in MonogDB. My question is how do I correctly define the `outputType` parameter in `.aggregate(agg, GpsRecord.class, List<List<GpsRecord>>)`?

```
@Repository
public class GpsRepositoryImpl implements GpsRepositoryCustom {

    private final MongoTemplate _mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public GpsRepositoryImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        _mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<GpsRecord>> aggregate(List<ObjectId> ids) {
        MatchOperation match = getMatchOperation(ids);
        GroupOperation group = getGroupOperation();
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, group);

        return _mongoTemplate
                   .aggregate(agg, GpsRecord.class, List<List<GpsRecord>>)
                   .getMappedResults();
    }

    private MatchOperation getMatchOperation(List<ObjectId> ids) {
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("trackRecord.id").in(ids);

        return new MatchOperation(criteria);
    }

    private GroupOperation getGroupOperation() {
        GroupOperation agg = Aggregation.group("trackRecord.id");

        return agg;
    }

}
```

**Edit**

Example of a GpsRecord

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("593d382c5b3ae715b2cac03d"),
    "_class": "gps",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [116.315148, 39.984538]
    },
    "dateTime": ISODate("2008-10-23T02:54:40Z"),
    "trackRecord": DBRef("trackRecords", ObjectId("593d382b5b3ae715b2cac029"))
}
```

Example of a TrackRecord

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("593d382b5b3ae715b2cac029"),
    "_class": "track",
    "name": "20081117155223.plt",
    "bbox": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[116.31949,39.999686],[116.325796,39.999686],[116.325796,40.009678],[116.31949,40.009678],[116.31949,39.999686]]]
    }
}
```

A `TrackRecord` consists of many `GpsRecord` objects, as in thousands of them or more.

So based on a `List` of `TrackRecord._id` I would like to return a `List` of `List<GpsRecord>`.

Comment: All nice, but this really does not tell anyone what your actual data looks like. Or what sort of parameters are actually input, Or indeed a simple visual representation of the returned data. To reach the wider audience you should show 1. Small selection of documents as viewed from the Mongo Shell, and **not** writeln or robomongo etc. 2. Same JSON format of expected output "sourced" from the selection of documents provided. I suspect you want something like a GeoJSON Multipoint output just going by the naming. But it's best if you show us instead.

Comment: I added some example JSON and hope it clarifies things a bit. I don't want to return a GeoJSON just yet, I just want to get the Objects back. In a later stage I will convert it into GeoJSON, I need to manipulate the "raw" dat first before turning it into GeoJSON. Thank you.

Comment: You can't return the result as a `List<List<…>>` from just calling `MongoOperations.aggregate(…)`. Query the results and transform these into the representation you're supposed to return.

Comment: @mp911de dammit, you are totally right! I just realized this myself. I'm sorry for the confusion. So it's not possible to return this query in any other form, then `List<...>`?

Comment: You map aggregation results to a specific type and since aggregation results are zero to many you get them as `List<…>`

Comment: @Stevan Did you got a solution . I am also struck with similar issue  like need ro return list of objects. like List<GpsRecord>> .in the belowreturn _mongoTemplate
                   .aggregate(agg, GpsRecord.class, List<GpsRecord>>)
                   .getMappedResults();

Comment: @Rithik_Star no, I didn't got the solution in the form of `List<List<GpsRecord>>`. I did work around the problem by using `List<GpsRecord>`. I basically ditched the aggregate function in MongoDB and implemented one in my own code.
I ended up implementing two solutions one with springboot and one with akka(plenty of actors doing the hard work).
I found that the akka solution was fast as in very fast. The bottle neck for the performance became MongoDB that couldn't feed the akka application fast enough, to much data needed to be pumped over. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want such aggregation:

```
db.GpsRecord.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:"trackRecord.$id", ...}}
])
```

> **Warning**: The pipeline cannot operate on values of the following types:  Binary, Symbol, MinKey, MaxKey, ***DBRef***, Code, and CodeWScope

But, if you use MongoDB >= 3.4.4, there is a new aggregation command `$objectToArray` which convert `DBRef` into array and allows you to group it.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#apr-21-2017